# mkfs fails if called after a 'dd' operation

Tags: linux, filesystems, dd, mkfs

I want to delete all files on one my eMMC blocks (e.g. /dev/mmcblk0p1) and re-create the filesystem afterward (with ext4).

So I unmount and erase:

```
umount /dev/mmcblk0p1
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0p1 bs=4096
```

Immediately after the dd I make the filesystem:

```
mkfs.ext4 -F -L MyLabel /dev/mmcblk0p1
```

I get the following error:

> Couldn't init profile successfully (error: 117).

Rebooting the system and the mkfs command will work just fine without any errors.

The `dmesg`  output if I try to do mkfs after dd (wihout reboot) is the following:

```
[ 7704.476779] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p1): ext4_map_blocks:596: inode #13: block 8290: comm mkfs.ext4: lblock 0 mapped to illegal pblock 8290 (length 1)
```

Why is that?

Comment: If you omit the -F what happens?

Comment: @roaima  I think the `-F` will prevent the confirmation prompt...thats why I have it there as to require no user input. What is your theory? would that help if I remove it?

Comment: The `-F` is "force the operation even if it seems wrong". I want to see what error/warning message - if any - is printed that ties in with the apparent failure to create a filesystem

Comment: Anything in dmesg?

Comment: @frostschutz Thanks! that is a good point. I added the dmesg output corresponding to mkfs in my question. Please see if you can understand that....I could not

Comment: @roaima Well I tried it with no -F and exactly the same message and behaviour. I have added dmesg output to my question

Comment: @DEKKER which kernel version do you have? seems like this error message was reported for 5.19 though it seems the context was a little different. maybe it's related regardless

Comment: @frostschutz I am using 5.4.0 and I also saw that bug report in 5.19, I do not think it relates to this problem :(

Comment: can you try executing `partprobe` before the `mkfs`?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
umount /dev/mmcblk0p1
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0p1 bs=4096
sync
mkfs.ext4 -F -L MyLabel /dev/mmcblk0p1
```

You seem to be running into buffer cache issues in the kernel. The `sync` forces the buffers flushed.

@roaima had great advice, avoid using `-F` as it may mask errors that mkfs would otherwise notify the user.

Comment: The `-F` potentially masks problems that `mkfs.ext4` would otherwise want to flag. Generally it's a bad idea to include it, as it switches off a number of safety checks such as refusing to format an existing filesystem